# How to show years on X axis when using matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I never used python and I have to do this as my first assignment. It took me 3 hours just to get to this point and I really need some help.

I have a one dimensional array with some numbers. I have to make a timeseries plot.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.load("abnormal.npy")

x = np.array(range(1,len(data)+1))
y = np.load("abnormal.npy")

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

As you can see the X axis now is the array range of my array.
How can I change this to date time 2002-2012 ?

Comment: Do you have the years stored somewhere? Right now, your x is just an array of numbers from 1 to 4000 and that's what's getting plotted. If you just want to change the tick label in your plot, you can also do that, but you need to know what is when. More info would be useful.

Comment: X is the days now since 2002-01-01 so I need it till 2012-12-31, but the X and Y array length should match, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, they should match in length.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have an array of dates that is exactly as long as your data array. If e.g. you know that there is one datapoint per day, you can create this array as

```
start = datetime.date(2002, 01, 01)
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(len(y))]
```

Complete example:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=4000))

start = datetime.date(2002, 01, 01)
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(len(y))]

plt.plot(dates,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just like do this,

```
import pandas as pd

y_len = 100
x = pd.date_range("20020101", freq='D', periods=y_len).strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
```

you just need get Y axis's lenght and point to the `y_len`, for you question

```
y_len = len(data)
```

the sample code output is,

```
['2002-01-01', '2002-01-02', '2002-01-03', '2002-01-04', '2002-01-05', '2002-01-06', '2002-01-07', '2002-01-08', '2002-01-09', '2002-01-10', '2002-01-11', '2002-01-12', '2002-01-13', '2002-01-14', '2002-01-15', '2002-01-16', '2002-01-17', '2002-01-18', '2002-01-19', '2002-01-20', '2002-01-21', '2002-01-22', '2002-01-23', '2002-01-24', '2002-01-25', '2002-01-26', '2002-01-27', '2002-01-28', '2002-01-29', '2002-01-30', '2002-01-31', '2002-02-01', '2002-02-02', '2002-02-03', '2002-02-04', '2002-02-05', '2002-02-06', '2002-02-07', '2002-02-08', '2002-02-09', '2002-02-10', '2002-02-11', '2002-02-12', '2002-02-13', '2002-02-14', '2002-02-15', '2002-02-16', '2002-02-17', '2002-02-18', '2002-02-19', '2002-02-20', '2002-02-21', '2002-02-22', '2002-02-23', '2002-02-24', '2002-02-25', '2002-02-26', '2002-02-27', '2002-02-28', '2002-03-01', '2002-03-02', '2002-03-03', '2002-03-04', '2002-03-05', '2002-03-06', '2002-03-07', '2002-03-08', '2002-03-09', '2002-03-10', '2002-03-11', '2002-03-12', '2002-03-13', '2002-03-14', '2002-03-15', '2002-03-16', '2002-03-17', '2002-03-18', '2002-03-19', '2002-03-20', '2002-03-21', '2002-03-22', '2002-03-23', '2002-03-24', '2002-03-25', '2002-03-26', '2002-03-27', '2002-03-28', '2002-03-29', '2002-03-30', '2002-03-31', '2002-04-01', '2002-04-02', '2002-04-03', '2002-04-04', '2002-04-05', '2002-04-06', '2002-04-07', '2002-04-08', '2002-04-09', '2002-04-10']
```

Comment: I want to have the labels on X like that, 2002-2012
But I can't do it like in this answer because then the X and Y array length doesn't match.
I think I need some special datetime function, however I have no idea how could I do it.

Comment: @CynthiaGS When I first answer the question, the describe is so pool, when the owner update the question describe, I had update the answer again, please check.